# Как выбрать элемент добавленный через ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

строки в таблицу добавляются динамически c помощью ajax,
мне нужно выбрать значение в этой ячейке

```
<td id="121">12</td>
```

пробовал обычный селектор , не получается , не видит в DOM добавленный элемент

```
var val=$('#121').text();
```

также есть кнопка , которая тоже добавляется динамически, её получилось выбрать, а вот данные в ячейке нет

```
 $("#table").on('click' ,'#12' ,function() {
        //alert('Кнопка нажата!');
```

так как же выбрать элемент , который добавился динамически?

Comment: Вот как раз таки последний вариант - решение, только с ошибкой, надо `#121`, а вы обращаетесь к `#12`. Ну и ещё вопрос, уверенны, что `#table` существует? Если он тоже создаётся после аякса, то тогда данный код не работает, т.к. в момент инициализации `#table` нет в DOM.

Comment: #table существует до аякса. Аякс добавляет в #table строки

Comment: Покажите пример данных, которые вам приходят.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте:

```
var val = setTimeout($('#121').text(), 1000);
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].